# Vue.js routing not working by using parameter as a route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to use parameter only as a route as I need URL like `localhost:8080/road`. But, it's not working properly.

My code:

```js
{
    path: "/:id",
    name: "id",
    component: Blog
},
```

Whenever I enter a url like `localhost:8080/dashboard` or any other URL, it uses the `Blog` component. How can I solve it?

Comment: What component do you expect it to use?

Comment: I have many components. If I enter url "localhost:8080/dashboard", it should use Dashboard component , if I enter url "localhost:8080/road", it should use Road component and so on. @Phil

Comment: So why not just make specific routes for those? You know all your components up-front so what's the point in trying to make this dynamic?

Comment: Ok. I will write separate route for separate component. Thank you @Phil

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to cut down on lines of code in your router definition, you could optimise this somewhat with an array of component names mapped to route definitions. For example

```js
const components = ["Blog", "Road", "Dashboard"]

// creates kebab-cased slugs from Pascal cased component names
const toSlug = component =>
  component.replace(/(?<=\w)[A-Z]/g, c => `-${c}`).toLowerCase()

const routes = components.map(name => ({
  name,
  path: toSlug(name),
  component: () => import(`@/components/${name}.vue`)
})
```

Using static parts in the `import` path like `@/components/` and `.vue` help Webpack optimise bundling.